# How to call the function by variable

Tags: php, function

I hope this question is not too simple, but I have no idea how to do this

```
$book = 'book';
$car = 'car';

function $book()
{ 
 return "Hello, world!";
}
function $car()
{
 return "WoW , The red car";
}
```

Comment: Good answers, for an unclear post. There is room for improvement here in order for it to potentially turn out as a good question. Can you clarify your question? Because it's hard to tell what you really want here.

Comment: [The suggestive edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19287802) IMHO, doesn't improve it whatsoever.

Comment: Please clarify if you want dynamically named functions, or you want to dynamically call (static) functions by the value in a variable.

Comment: @CJDennis I'm curious to know why you're asking for clarification, but [you accepted the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19287802). IMHO, the question is still unclear and my vote for it to close still stands.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner The edit got it from 1% to 50%. It was an improvement, even if it didn't get it to 99%.

Comment: @CJDennis Yeah, I was going to mention something like that, strangely enough. It's "some" improvement, but the body of it should have a big more *"oomf"*. If you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a function with variable name like this:

[Variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

```
<?php
    $a = 'book';

    function book() {
        echo 'book function';
    }

    // this is equivalent to book()
    $a();
```

So to expand a little bit:

```
<?php
$functions = ['book', 'car'];

function book() {
    return "Hello, world!";
}

function car() {
    return "WoW , The red car";
}

foreach ($functions as $function) {
    echo $function() .'<br>';
}
```

The OUTPUT would be:

```
Hello, world!
WoW , The red car
```

Another way of doing it to get same output:

[Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
$book = function() {
    echo 'book function';
};

$book();
```

In this case, the above function doesn't have an actual name and is represented by a variable.

And let me give you an example:

```
<?php
    $book = function() {
        echo 'book function';
    };

    $a = $book;

    echo $a();
```

So, to expand in the same manner:

```
<?php
$functions = ['book', 'car'];

$book = function () {
    return "Hello, world!";
};

$car = function() {
    return "WoW , The red car";
};

foreach ($functions as $function) {
    echo ${$function}(). '<br>';
}
```

DEMO:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1972f1acd72984d459efbfb308680aaa9d7a1fad

Answer (score 2):

You cant do that, <strike>you have 2 options</strike>.

A couple of ways:

Use [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php):

```
<?php
$book = 'book';
$car = 'car';

function book()
{ 
 return "Hello, world!";
}

function car()
{
 return "WoW , The red car";
}

echo $book();
echo $car();
```

Or [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php):

```
<?php
$book = function () { 
 return "Hello, world!";
};

$car = function() {
 return "WoW , The red car";
};

echo $book();
echo $car();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$book = function() { 
    return "Hello, world!";
};
echo $book(); // invoke it
```

Answer (score 1):

Class

```
 class foo
 {
     public function __invoke(){ echo "hello"; }
 }
```

Test

```
 $obj = new foo;
 $obj();
```

Output

```
hello
```

[Online Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/904bd01b1534583750aa2d9f95fd09a483376c20)

You can also use reflection (to call an existing function as a string)

```
 (new ReflectionFunction('print_r'))->invoke("hello");
```

Outputs

```
  hello
```

ReflectionMethod is nice too, because it maintains state of the object, for example

```
 class foo{

     protected $bar;

     public function setBar($bar){ $this->bar = $bar;}

     public function bar(){ echo $this->bar; }
 }


 $obj = new foo;

 $obj->setBar("good bye");

 (new ReflectionMethod($obj, 'bar'))->invoke($obj);
```

Outputs

```
good bye
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - I'm not up to PHPv7 yet,  Well not in production code anyway.  Maybe 3 more months.  Spent 2 weeks on PHP7 compatibility recently (true story)

Comment: Its hard to keep up lately, just wait till.. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrow_functions

Comment: `echo (new ReflectionFunction('sprintf'))->invokeArgs(['%s', 'Hello']);` ;p +1